# Silverlight grid not filling entire space

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xaml, silverlight

I have content object in wcf.
I try store in content property grid but it not fill the entire length.

Function return grid:

```
private Grid ChangeContentObject()
        {
            Grid g = new Grid();
            g.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

            g.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            g.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

            ColumnDefinition columnDefinitionForPath = new ColumnDefinition();
            columnDefinitionForPath.Width = new GridLength(4,GridUnitType.Star);

            ColumnDefinition columnDefinitionForEmpty = new ColumnDefinition();
            columnDefinitionForEmpty.Width = new GridLength(6, GridUnitType.Star);

            g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinitionForPath);
            g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinitionForEmpty);

            WindowsShapes.Path p = new WindowsShapes.Path();
            p.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);
            p.StrokeThickness = 2;

            p.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            var b = new Binding
            {
                Source = "M50,0 L0,0 L0,50 L50,50"
            };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(p, WindowsShapes.Path.DataProperty, b);

            p.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;

            g.Children.Add(p);
            Grid.SetColumn(p, 0);

            return g;
        }
```

Code for set content:

```
objectVisual.Content = ChangeContentObject();
```

objectVisual property:

```
objectVisual.VerticalAlignment = Stretch
objectVisual.VerticalAlignment
objectVisual.Width = 100
objectVisual.Height = 50
```

I get next result:

[image]

Why grid does not fill the entire length?

Comment: I am not adept at WPF, but perhaps the container is some sort of FlowLayoutPanel or ... I would say some form of ScrollViewer? Someone with more WPF experience will surely give you a short and more to the point answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Grid` has 2 columns. The second column is empty, and therefore collapsed, so you can't see it. Binding something to it solves the "problem". Also, modified your `Path` data for this demo, because the one you had is no good. Take a look:

[image]

```
private Grid ChangeContentObject()
{
    Grid g = new Grid();
    g.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

    g.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    g.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

    // add grid line to show columns border
    g.ShowGridLines = true;

    ColumnDefinition columnDefinitionForPath = new ColumnDefinition();
    columnDefinitionForPath.Width = new GridLength(4, GridUnitType.Star);

    ColumnDefinition columnDefinitionForEmpty = new ColumnDefinition();
    columnDefinitionForEmpty.Width = new GridLength(6, GridUnitType.Star);

    g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinitionForPath);
    g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinitionForEmpty);

    var p1 = new Path();
    p1.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);
    p1.StrokeThickness = 2;
    p1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
    p1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

    var b1 = new Binding
    {
        // modified path data
        Source = "M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100"
    };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(p1, Path.DataProperty, b1);

    var p2 = new Path();
    p2.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);
    p2.StrokeThickness = 2;
    p2.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
    p2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

    var b2 = new Binding
    {
        // modified path data
        Source = "M 100,10 C 100,30 -200,100 100,300"
    };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(p2, Path.DataProperty, b2);

    g.Children.Add(p1);
    g.Children.Add(p2);
    Grid.SetColumn(p1, 0);
    Grid.SetColumn(p2, 1);

    return g;
}
```

**Update:**

Normally, a `Grid` would stretch and expand on its own, no need at all to *"fill it with empty space"*. The problem here is caused by the fact that you're placing your `Grid` enclosed within `objectVisual`, which apparently is a `ContentControl` (you didn't make it clear in your post). So, instead you should make `objectVisual` a type derived from a `Panel`, like, let's say, another `Grid`.

And then, replace this:

```
objectVisual.Content = ChangeContentObject();
```

with this:

```
objectVisual.Children.Add(ChangeContentObject());
```

And you'll get what you want:

[image]

**Update 2:**

Well, your **pastebin** code is slightly different from your original code, and although that would work too, you misunderstood what I said about the `Grid`. You don't need your `var gridChild`, you can keep the second column empty, like in your original question. Notice I commented it out. So, in order to clarify, I am posting full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sample code below. The result looks just like the second image I posted above previously.

**UserControl CS:**

```
public partial class SilverlightControl3 : UserControl
{
    public SilverlightControl3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        objectVisual.Children.Add(ChangeContentObject());
    }

    private Grid ChangeContentObject()
    {
        Grid g = new Grid();
        g.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        g.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        g.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

        // add grid line to show columns border
        g.ShowGridLines = true;

        ColumnDefinition columnDefinitionForPath = new ColumnDefinition();
        columnDefinitionForPath.Width = new GridLength(4, GridUnitType.Star);

        ColumnDefinition columnDefinitionForEmpty = new ColumnDefinition();
        columnDefinitionForEmpty.Width = new GridLength(6, GridUnitType.Star);

        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinitionForPath);
        g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinitionForEmpty);

        var p1 = new Path();
        p1.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        p1.StrokeThickness = 2;
        p1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        p1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

        g.Children.Add(p1);
        Grid.SetColumn(p1, 0);

        var b1 = new Binding
        {
            Source = "M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100"
        };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(p1, Path.DataProperty, b1);

        // you dont necessarily need this here, you can keep it empty like before
        /*
        var gridChild = new Grid();
        g.Children.Add(gridChild);
        Grid.SetColumn(gridChild, 1);
        */

        return g;
    }
}
```

**UserControl XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication4.SilverlightControl3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid x:Name="objectVisual" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication4.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <local:SilverlightControl3 />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I try use grid in two column and i get incorrect result again. How do I fill the second column with empty space?

Comment: @noobprogrammer please see our **Update** above.

Comment: @noobprogrammer please see our **Update 2**. This is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which means you can use it in a brand new project to confirm results.